# How to register a callback for SignOut Event in Firebase Anonymous login?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to see if its possible to somehow register a callback for onSignOut in firebase?

I am trying to use login users anonymously. I have registered for onAuthStateChanged() but its only fired when you you login. I want a function callback when this login sessions finishes.

OnDisconnect() listener is specifically for the database socket dropping off. But I need a specific way to know if the anonymous login is signed out.

Comment: You'll need to [listen to the `onAuthStateChanged()` event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way you can do it:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if(user)
      {//logged in}
    else
      {//logged out}
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
signOut(getAuth()).then((e) => {
  /* your code */
});
```